# iOS 5 - Capture the return value from a method being called asynchronously

Tags: objective-c, ios5, grand-central-dispatch

I have a method, fetchFromWeb, that returns an object. I want to call this method asynchronously from GCD. Can someone explain how I would capture the return value from a method being called asynchronously?

**Or**, should I set the object value and then set up some sort of notification and not explicitly get the return value from this method at all?

Here is what I have and thanks!

```
        dispatch_async(kBGQueue, ^{


            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kURL];
            [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchFromWeb:) 
                                   withObject:data 
                                waitUntilDone:YES];

            //Need to get the return value from method fetchFromWeb in selector....

        });
```

Comment: Do you really want to tie up your main thread with a "fetchFromWeb" operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

dataWithContentsOfURL is only for file URLs, not Web URLs. Its not asynchronous. Even if you send it off to its own thread using GCD its not the correct way to do it.

If you need to go out to the web, you need to use NSURLConnection.

Use + (void)sendAsynchronousRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request queue:(NSOperationQueue *)queue completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLResponse*, NSData*, NSError*))handler

You were on the right track initially -- you don't want a return value from the method. Let the completion handler block set a property (ivar) with the data you received, and, as you suggested, use a notification at the end of the block to alert you that its done. That notification can fire a method to access the property and you can get at your data object.

Comment: I am assuming that I'll need to implement the NSURLConnection delegate methods?

Comment: No, NSURLConnection with the delegate methods is another approach you can take -- it allows you to respond to receiving data in chunks, react to beginning / end events, etc. Within the world of NSURLConnection, this is like a simplified approach. The only problem with this approach, in my experience, is that it doesn't scale well. If you are making a lot these calls simultaneously, (if you were going out to get 50 thumbnails or something), it breaks down. Too many threads gets spawned and requests just never come back. You would have to use a different approach. Operation queues work well.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, because you can't get a return from it. Use `dispatch_sync` with the main dispatch queue instead, which has the same effect as `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:YES`.

```
dispatch_async(kBGQueue, ^{

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:kURL];

    __block id result = nil; // Use the correct type here.
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        result = [self fetchFromWeb:data];
    });

    // Do something with result here.
});
```

---

*Edit*: I should add that, as noted by Jason Howlin, you shouldn't use `dataWithContentsOfURL:` in shipping applications. It's okay to use as a quick-`n`-dirty debugging tool, but `NSURLConnection` is the correct way to do it. As of iOS 5.0's `+sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`, it's not that much harder to use.